# How can we setup hdri background image so that camera can move around an object which appear stable relatively to the hdri image?

Tags: animation, camera, hdri

What I want to do is to render an animation where the rendered objects are not moving, but the camera is moving around them. OK for it.

But from that I want to use a hdri image in background which is also rendered.

My issue is the following: when the camera moves around the mesh objects I want to render, the background image is not 'synchronized' with the camera movement (and relatively to the rendered objects).
The consequence is these rendered objects seem to move relatively to the background image.

Is it possible to avoid that?
I'm thinking about camera tracking to compensate this unwanted effect.
But is there a more simple way to do that? Or can camera tracking be a solution (if yes how)?

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45299/moving-camera-with-hdri-environment-texture-image/97527#97527

Comment: Have you tried mapping the hdri onto the interior of a giant sphere with an emit shader?

Comment: @Sazerac, no I haven't yet. I think the effect will be the same, but maybe this sphere could be more easy to adjust than the environment texture?

Comment: If the sphere is static with respect to the objects, I think this would be fine. You may get some parallax errors if the camera movements are too large or the size of the sphere, or if parts of the hdri depict stuff that should be close. I admit I haven't tried it though.

Comment: @lemon I'm having a hard time understanding exactly what you want to do. An image that is used as world environment is only an image taken from a single point in space that covers 360 degrees. It works only if the camera rotates, If the camera is displaced then the image cannot generate a new point of view. It is not a 3d environment. You would need a new image that is taken from the new camera position. Can you elaborate on what kind of motion are you talking about?

Comment: @cegaton, yes. I'm afraid you're right and what I want to do may be impossible if we want an exact 3D projection. My hope was a mean to adjust the environment texture posrotscale so that the result appears "coherent enough". What I want to do is the camera move around half of an object pointing at it. If this object was a cube, the camera will film from a side to its opposite, so will turn 90 or 100 degrees, something around that.

Comment: You can do that by animating the coordinates for the image used as environment texture on the world. There is no need to use a sphere (it is basically the same idea, the world texture is  just a big sphere that surrounds the scene)

Comment: @cegaton, in this context, what I fail to understand is how this sphere is centered and what can be its radius (or is it like 'infinite')?

Comment: The world is a sphere that surrounds the scene and is infinitely far away. I don't know where the center is, I would suspect that is at  0, 0, 0 but that is just a guess.